# Uploading Matlab files in github

Tags: matlab, github

Any of you have any idea how to upload matlab files onto github?

I can copy paste the code from .m files onto github repository file, but i can't upload the .mat file. There is no matlab language facility in github available for code highlighting which I know. But is there any way that I can upload the .mat files (trained neural nets, etc., are saved in .mat files).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do this through the web interface? At the moment, GitHub doesn't support that. But the primary way of getting things into or out of GitHub should be to use a Git client, like the standard `git` command line tool, the GitHub GUIs, or Atlassian SourceTree.

Answer (score 3):

git doesn't care what kind of files you upload, it just handles text more efficiently. `.mat` files are binary files, and you can upload them just as well as any other binary file. The github web gui just doesn't have any facilities to show you the contents. Catering for all sorts of binary files would be a completely unreasonable goal for a service like github.

If you want to inspect the contents, you'll probably need to process the data anyways, so you'll need Matlab for that. Clone the repo and view the files locally.